# How to write a copyright message using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating some graphs using matplotlib, and I want to be able to write a copyright message and my website address at the bottom of the image.

Something like:

> © ACME Corp www.example.com

Does anyone know how I may do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this answer your question but you can put any text in a figure with

```
 text(x, y, s, fontdict=None, **kwargs)
```

some examples of fonts are in [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/stix_fonts_demo.html)

Answer (score 3):

To write text in the figure outside the axis area, use [figtext](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=figtext#matplotlib.pyplot.figtext).

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.text(1,-1, 'Copyright: \xa9 Rafael Valero-Fernandez 2023', 
     horizontalalignment='right',
     verticalalignment='bottom')
```

That looks like this:

[image]

All the code in my case:

```
# library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn3

name_file = "venn_diagram_purpose"

# Use the venn3 function
# Make a Basic Venn
plt.close('all')

v = venn3(subsets=(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
          set_labels = ('Skills', 
                        'Opportunity',
                        'Interest'))
v.get_label_by_id('111').set_text('Destiny')
v.get_label_by_id('100').set_visible(False)
v.get_label_by_id('010').set_visible(False)
v.get_label_by_id('001').set_visible(False)
v.get_label_by_id('110').set_visible(False)
v.get_label_by_id('011').set_visible(False)
v.get_label_by_id('101').set_visible(False)
""" v.get_patch_by_id('111').set_color('blue')
v.get_patch_by_id('100').set_color('white')
v.get_patch_by_id('010').set_color('white')
v.get_patch_by_id('001').set_color('white')
v.get_patch_by_id('110').set_color('white')
v.get_patch_by_id('011').set_color('white')
v.get_patch_by_id('101').set_color('white') """
# Add title and annotation
plt.title("Where is your destiny?")

plt.text(1,-1, 'Copyright: \xa9 Rafael Valero-Fernandez 2023', 
     horizontalalignment='right',
     verticalalignment='bottom')


plt.show()
plt.savefig(f'{name_file}.png')
```